# How to delete Google Calendars in Maya (Loki 0.4)?

Tags: calendar

After adding my Google Account to maya I want to reset the Application. But there's no possibility to delete the shown calendars!

Anny ideas?

Thanks

Comment: There should be a better method but if you don't care about data stored in calendar you should try `sudo apt-get purge maya-calendar` and afterwards `sudo apt-get install maya-calendar` and check if that solved it.

Comment: Don't forget `sudo apt-get update` before.

Comment: These commands are helpful to reinstall the `maya-calendar` package (that is the application) but they don't do anything with user data (that is calendars, configuration etc.).

Comment: Sorry @lemonslice , I thought that `sudo apt-get purge` would get rid of the config files and installing again will have a brand new result. :-(

Comment: Actually, it does get rid of the system configuration files but not the user ones. Anyway no problems at all, this site is for learning from each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can hover over the calendar name in the gear menu (top right) and a trash icon appears. However, there are two special system calendars (Birthdays&Anniversaries / Personal) that you cannot delete but  hide.

[image]